# Anyone using grailsflow in its Plug-in or Demo version?

Tags: java, grails, grails-plugin

Grailsflow seems to be broken (as of Jan 2010) with Grails 1.2 or above, in both 'demo' and the plug-in flavours.  Is there anyone out there using it?  Have moved code out of the plug-in into my BootStrap.groovy, so the app will start.

@see  [jcatalog forum post](http://forums.jcatalog.com/forums/posts/list/142.page)

But still need to work around or resolve the error in all views.
  See stack trace below:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag : java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'common' on null object at /Users/saleram/.grails/1.2.1/projects/dataentry/plugins/grailsflow-core-1.0-rc1/grails-app/views/process/list.gsp:20

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:613)

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag : java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'common' on null object at /Users/saleram/.grails/1.2.1/projects/dataentry/plugins/grailsflow-core-1.0-rc1/grails-app/views/process/list.gsp:20

    at Users_saleram__grails_1_2_1_projects_dataentry_plugins_grailsflow_core_1_0_rc1_grails_app_views_process_list_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(Users_saleram__grails_1_2_1_projects_dataentry_plugins_grailsflow_core_1_0_rc1_grails_app_views_process_list_gsp:27)

    at Users_saleram__grails_1_2_1_projects_dataentry_plugins_grailsflow_core_1_0_rc1_grails_app_views_process_list_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(Users_saleram__grails_1_2_1_projects_dataentry_plugins_grailsflow_core_1_0_rc1_grails_app_views_process_list_gsp)

    at Users_saleram__grails_1_2_1_projects_dataentry_plugins_grailsflow_core_1_0_rc1_grails_app_views_process_list_gsp.run(Users_saleram__grails_1_2_1_projects_dataentry_plugins_grailsflow_core_1_0_rc1_grails_app_views_process_list_gsp:41)

    ... 1 more

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'common' on null object

    ... 4 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'common' on null object

    at GrailsflowI18nTagLib$_closure1.doCall(GrailsflowI18nTagLib.groovy:30)

    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Seems (since Feb 2010) with Grails 1.2.x, Grailsflow is 'broken' at least in the GSP... this is quite terrible.  Does anyone have experience with other lightweight open source workflow libraries in Grails apps?


--
Same for me, with Grails 1.2 final version ...
I commented the lines in method def doWithApplicationContext and migrated the creation of FlowStatus entries to my application Boostrap and now the application starts. 

But it crashes if I try to load a view. It seems that there's another issue with the GTag

Answer (score 1):

The error is because it is unable to load the resource bundles for the messages. I moved them out into the default messages.properties file and modified the GSP's accordingly. Now the application starts fine and I can access the pages fine but there are still some errors as below..

```
Caused by: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException: Invocation of method 'execute' on target class [class NodeActivatorJob] failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: updateProcessService for class: ProcessManagerService
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: updateProcessService for class: ProcessManagerService
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:241)
    at ProcessManagerService.sendEvent(ProcessManagerService.groovy:359)
    at ProcessManagerService$sendEvent$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at ProcessManagerService.sendEvent(ProcessManagerService.groovy:279)
    at ProcessManagerService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b8eb8e77.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at ProcessManagerService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8e9fc43f.sendEvent(<generated>)
```

Has anyone been able to setup the demo fine?

Comment: Krishna, thank you for the update.  I think we may need to contact the GrailsFlow author(s) as I do not think the plug-in is actively maintained.